# Strange MPMoviePlayerController view rotation/animation...

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller

i´ve a MPMoviePlayerController which plays a video within a small frame with the default controls. If i press the "fullscreen" button on the mediaplayer control, everything works fine -  the video is still playing. 
When the video has finished, i want to close the fullscreen view and go back to the non-fullscreen viewcontroller.

My app is landscape only. I´ve tested the "setFullscreen" property to switch back when the  MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification gets called- that works. But there appears a view rotation from portrait to landscape which is wrong. I just need landscape to landscape.

Any ideas why this happens?

```
 self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [self.moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    self.moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    self.moviePlayerController.fullscreen = NO;
    self.moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

    [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame: someMovieFrame];

    [tempImageScrollView addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackCompletePSV:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.moviePlayerController];
    [self.moviePlayerController play];



- (void) moviePlaybackCompletePSV:(NSNotification*) notification {

    MPMoviePlayerController *mymoviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:mymoviePlayerController];

    NSLog(@"PSV moviePlaybackComplete!");

    // movie fadeout transition ====================
    self.moviePlayerController.view.alpha = 1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.moviePlayerController.view.alpha = 0;

                         if ([self.moviePlayerController isFullscreen]) {
                             NSLog(@"PSV fullscreen movieplayer deleted");

                             [self.moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
                         }
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [mymoviePlayerController stop];
                         [mymoviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];

                         [self.moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
                         self.moviePlayerController = nil;

                    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the movie player goes fullscreen, your parent view controller's `viewWillDisappear` / `viewDidDisappear` is called, and when it returns to normal size, your parent view controller's `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidAppear` is called.

It sounds like something in those methods is inadvertently getting called twice.

If this isn't enough to answer your question, please post the appropriate methods in your parent controller.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, i´ve just looked at the parent viewcontroller but there´s nothing about views or size in the viewWill/DidAppear methods. I´ve just also tested the app on an iOS5 iPad 1. Strange that on this device, everything is fine - no (portrait to landscape) rotation. So something iOS6 depended? Any ideas?

Comment: I´ve just implemented landscape rotation only to the new iOS6 VC methods "supportedInterfaceOrientations" and "preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation" which contains the movie player. Still the same rotation issue. Hope someone can help me..

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6 has some changes about device's rotation and orientation handling. See more here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012166-CH1-SW19

First add all the orientation that need supported by your movie player to the field `Supported interface orientations` (or create this field if missed) in your `.plist`.

In your case, maybe you used a `UInavigationController` or `UITabbarController` as root view. If so, let's try subclass them and override these method (if you used a `UIViewController` as root just override them in `.m` file):
:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Next add below methods to your `MPMoviePlayerController`'s`.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;

}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Just try, hope it works.